# Exit for-statement once condition is reached

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am trying to compare two workbooks to pick out any rows that are dissimilar between them. I have created the code below to do this, but I was hoping there was something similar to a `continue` which I could use inside of the if-statement to exit the innermost `for each`-loop once a difference is found. Is there any obvious way to do this? I guess I could use a `goto`-statement, but I'd prefer to avoid this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb_new As Workbook, wb_old As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range, c_old As Range, c_new As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb_new = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
    Set wb_old = Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")

    For Each ws In wb_old.Worksheets
        For i = 0 To 275
            Set r = ws.Range("A1:Q1").Offset(i, 0)
            For Each c_old In r
                Set c_new = wb_new.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").Offset(i, c_old.Column - 1)
                If c_new <> c_old Then
                    Debug.Print c_new.Address
                End If
            Next c_old
        Next i
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Exit For` (available in vba, aka `Break` in some languages) and `Continue` (not available in vba, but in some other languages) do not have the same behavior in general. With `Exit For` you exit the inner loop totally, whereas with `Continue` you jump to the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have already answered your own question in your title - simply use `Exit For`.

Here is a reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/exit-statement

Comment: The link points to the VB.Net docs.  Here's the VBA page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/fornext-statement?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: Ugh - I should have recalled that was the syntax in VBA - especially, when writing the title for the question, as you mention :) Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an `Exit For` statement.

```
            If c_new <> c_old Then
                Debug.Print c_new.Address
                Exit For    'exits the inner loop
            End If
```